# Update "What is Reputation" page: more comprehensive list of rep-loss methods

Tags: feature-request, reputation, help-center

Currently, under the ["what is reputation?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) help page, we have a list of 7 ways you can gain reputation, and 5 ways you can lose it (receive downvote to question, receive downvote to answer, give downvote, place bounty, be flagged as a spammer/offender).

Unfortunately, those 5 ways are not actually the only ways for someone to lose rep, as evidenced by [several](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6787/why-reputation-is-lost-when-a-question-is-deleted) [recent](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6804/i-just-lost-15-in-one-go-a-fine) [questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6788/why-am-i-losing-two-reputation) just on meta.ELU.  To be fair, some of the additional reasons are somewhat touched upon in the middle of a subsequent paragraph, but I think they'd be better of spelled out completely as part of the list. Specifically, I'd like to add:

> - accepted answer is un-accepted: -15
> - upvoted answer is un-upvoted: -10
> - upvoted question is un-upvoted: -5
> - post *(question or answer)* is deleted: lose all rep points gained from that post

Suggestions for better wording, especially on that last item, are welcome.  :-)  Also, are there any other ways that I've missed?

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that any reversals will cause a reversal of reputation. At best it's pedantry, at worst it's confusing to new users. What benefit would this serve?

Answer (score 7):

The list in the help page is meant to identify the key aspects of the system where users can gain or lose reputation or, more specifically, what they should do to gain it and what can cause them to lose it - it's not an all-inclusive list. Nor should it be, because it's a help article and we *want people to read it*. If we start cramming in too much information then it just starts looking like a book and people will ignore it. No one that's just learning the site wants to read about all the niches of the system and how these events can be reversed, but we do have a [Reputation FAQ here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) for the power users who want more information.

I'm not sure how useful it is to list all the *reversals* of things that can happen, as it seems pretty obvious that when something gets undone, the effects get undone too. Reversals also don't happen nearly as often as the actual events themselves which, again, are the things we want users to focus on. As an aside, a post being deleted doesn't *always* cause a reputation loss. Sometimes it can actually cause a user to gain reputation back, in cases where the post was heavily downvoted.

But to touch on the three questions you linked - adding these to the list wouldn't have solved any of their problems.

- The first question is someone who knows that deletion causes reputation reversal and just disagrees with that feature / wants it to be changed.
- The second could have been solved by explaining that there is a "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of their reputation history. They were merely confused because they weren't seeing why they lost the reputation. Having a list of things that can cause it wouldn't help them identify why they lost it in their specific case.
- The third was a user who just didn't know what the reputation history was, and thus didn't know where to look to find out why their reputation decreased. Suffering the same problem as number two.

Comment: Alternatively then, could there be a link from the help center to the FAQ page?